# data.table fread how to ignore empty line

Tags: r, data.table

It looks like if the second line in the file is empty, the column names will not be read. I've played with switches such as header, skip, from the documentation but can't get it to work.

In case the second line in my file is empty, how to ignore this fact and still read the first line as column names?

the second line is empty:

```
> fread('c1 c2\n\n1 2\n3 4\n')

   V1 V2
1:  1  2
2:  3  4
```

the second line is not empty:

```
> fread('c1 c2\n1 2\n3 4\n')
   c1 c2
1:  1  2
2:  3  4
```

Comment: @VasilyA will reopen your question, but that doesn't this is a clear duplicate imo because the answer you accepted is younger than the answers below

Comment: @VasilyA If one way or another you agree it should be closed, better to just leave it alone. Too many dupes on SO go unmarked as such and it's better to link them somehow than not at all... as happened for two years in this case. By going after the folks closing dupes, you're further disincentivizing the making of such links. Worth considering, anyway.

Comment: I absolutely agree that marking dupes is necessary and useful work, didn't want to disincentivize it, sorry if it looked like this. I'm just not an expert in SO rules and traditions, that's why I asked what is the logic of choosing one of the two. Thank you for your time and sorry for making unnecessary flood.

Answer (score 12):

The current version of `data.table` (1.9.8+) adds a `blank.lines.skip` argument that seems to resolve this problem:

```
fread('c1 c2\n\n1 2\n3 4\n',blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
#    c1 c2
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround: read the file with `fread` then use some other tool to read only the first line correctly to add it as column names.

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)

str_data <- 'c1 c2\n\n1 2\n3 4\n'
dt <- fread(str_data)

df.header <- read_delim(str_data, delim = " ", n_max = 0)
setnames(dt, names(df.header))

> dt
   c1 c2
1:  1  2
2:  3  4
```

Comment: @Jim Green please consider accepting one of the answers if they solved your problem.