# using readr to import big data file with different row lengths and whitespace as delimiter

Tags: r, readr

I have an issue to Read a big file (close to 2000000 rows) using the readr package.

Why do I want to use the readr package. My data file can containing ASCII control characters (0x01 equal to ascii 26 equal to CTRL+Z) that stops the execution of `read.table()` and I note that the `readr` package is not sensitive to that problem.

My file has different row lenghts thus I would used the `fill=TRUE` if I could use the `read.table()`.

I tried to use `read_table` of the readr package but without success because it seems to not find whitespaces as columns separator.

I tried to use `read_delim`. with the code `read_delim(file,delim=" ")`. The separator were found but the first row is considered as the main length of my data frame and thus lengther rows were truncated.

Does anyone got an advice ?

Comment: Did you try the `fread` function the `data.table` package?

Comment: Could you show how you've tried using `read_file()` ? This functions was created precisely to [read text file where columns are separated by whitespace](http://search.r-project.org/library/readr/html/read_table.html). Thinking of an alternative, do you know the `width` of each column ? or column initial and final positions ?

Comment: I've just tried with fread, but it seems to stopped at an empty line, do you have a clue to stop that error?

Comment: You could try to set `blank.lines.skip = TRUE`, see `?fread` for info on all the parameters.

Comment: I understand Something on read_table using. It seems to not work if
 
" Each line is the same length, and each field is in the same position in every line. It's similar to read.table, but rather parsing like a file delimited by arbitrary amounts of whitespace, it first finds empty columns and then parses like a fixed width file. "

indeed, I tried with 10 identical lines and it works, and if i had a shorter line at the beginning it don't

Comment: There is an error when I try to use blank.line.skip=TRUE in fread


> essai2<-fread(file2,sep=" ",blank.lines.skip = TRUE)

Error in fread(file2, sep = " ", blank.lines.skip = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (blank.lines.skip = TRUE)

Comment: fread blank.lines.skip is only available on data.table 1.9.7 which is not already in CRAN [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539408/data-table-fread-how-to-ignore-empty-line) and unfortunatly I don't suceed to install it.

Comment: could you try `read_delim(file,delim="")` ? Note I removed the space between quotation marks.

Comment: read_delim(file,delim="") gave me the following result:

a data frame of one column with one line of my data on each rows.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed in collect my data (from the file named file) into a dataframe (rtcm1) using the following code:

```
 #create a vector for named the columns, actually I used more for define the number of columns to be used to import my file

 col<-paste("V",1:17,sep="")

#use read_delim of the readr packages with a separator is whitespace. I don't really know why but I need to put quote="" to collect all my datas. maybe to not consider "" as quoting characters.

 rtcm1<-read_delim(file,delim=" ",col_names=col,quote="")
```

With such solution NA's fill cells with no datas and warnings are given by the function but it seems to works well.